# Dynamic allocation in java or c++

Tags: java, c++, memory, dynamic, allocation

If I have a pointer in C++, let's say `int* array;`, I allocate memory for the array with

```
array=new int[10];
```

Then, I initialize all 10 elements of the array, with 0,1,2,3...
After that, I do `array=new int[15];`
will the initial first 10 values still be there? I assume not, correct me if I'm wrong.

**In C there is the function `realloc`, which has the effect described above. Is there any equivalent in C++ or java? 
How can I dynamically expand an array (without using Vector class, and without copying the array each time in another array with double capacity) in C++ or Java?**

Comment: You're correct.  It will get replaced with an array of zeroes in Java.

Comment: No, it will get replaced with an array of random values (actually what was in memory before). C++ does not initialize array-contents!

Comment: I think this is too vague a question - several issues across different languages...

Comment: @Marius I was referring to Java.  Apologies, I should've said that.

Comment: I think you should replace your "java OR c++" to "java AND c++" or "java VS c++" in question.

Comment: Interesting that most of the answers seem to be ignoring the second half of the question, which is the actual interesting part...

Comment: @Daniel because the second part makes no sense. It refers to "the effect described above". But what effect? In C++, it is a memory leak.

Comment: the second part is about dynamic expanding of array

Comment: Note, `realloc` doesn't necessarily just resize the old block of memory.  If there's not enough free space after the array to do so, it will allocate a new array and copy the old values over.  That's why it gives you back a pointer; the pointer may be to an entirely different location than the one you passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you do `new int[X]` where `X` is an integer, in both C++ and Java, you obtain a reference to a newly allocated array.

In Java, arrays are automatically initialized so that each entry has its default value (0 for primitive data types, null for reference data types). In C++, the array is not initialized, you get garbage on it.

If you do:

```
array = new int[10];
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 1;
// etc
array = new int[15];
```

the second time you create an array and put a reference to it in the variable `array`, you simply lose the reference to your first array. Since it is a *new* array, it will obey the language's rules for newly allocate arrays: in Java, array will now point to an array of size 15 filled with zeroes; in C++, array will point to an array of size 15 filled with garbage.

In Java, the lost array will be eventually garbage collected for you. In C++, you've just created a memory leak.

Both languages forbid you to *resize* or, as you put, *dynamically expand* an array. You can create a new one, copy everything from the old one to the new one, and discard the old one. They might provide methods that make these operations for you, but you won't expand the existing array, you will simply create a new one and copy the data from the old one to the new one.

In Java there's no *realloc* (but it has `Arrays.copyOf`, which works similarly), and in C++ (and C as well), `realloc` won't really *extend* the array; it will allocate more memory *elsewhere*, deallocate the memory previously allocated, and return the new pointer: you'd have to replace any existing pointers to the new address!

Finally, for collection classes that dynamically resize themselves, they usually have an internal array and, whenever that array gets full, the class does all that resizing internally: it allocates a new one, bigger, copies the elements, and discards the old one. Since the array is completely encapsulated in the class, you don't need to worry about references to the old array as I explained above.

Comment: Best answer so far :)

Could you detail more on the last part, with realloc? why does it work in C and not in C++ (for primitive types, I mean)

Comment: How so, "it doesn't work in C++"?

Comment: @Radu `realloc` works in the same way in C and C++.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misread your answer.

Well, if I use realloc to reallocate more memory let's say sizeof(int) more memory, I thought it will only copy the array if there is no space for reallocation in that place. Otherwise, it would simply ask for a bigger block of memory, thus extending the array?

Comment: @Radu, I'm not sure about the exact behavior. I think it might indeed just extend the block if there's space, but then how would you know if the runtime thinks there's enough space? Depending on the use case, you'd need to check if the newly allocated block of memory is in the same position (and update old pointers if the address has changed), or if you simply have a single pointer that you are replacing, you simply don't care about it -- if the address changes or stays the same, your code will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

In java memory management is under control of JVM. That is the beautity of java. You can use System.arraycopy() function to make a copy of an array. If your aim is to expand array just give a bigger array as destination array.

On the other hand you can use collections framework for dynamically expanding collections.

Answer (score 2):

The heart of array concept, both in C++ and Java, is **fixed** size collection. `realloc` may look like some kind of backdoor in this conception, but it still doesn't promise to expand given array - it may create array in other location, copy original content and release original memory. And quite probably it will.
So, if you want variable size collection, use `std::vector` in C++ and `ArrayList` in Java. Or you can code this functionality by yourself. But I'm afraid you will have to start with own memory allocator, as you cannot make standard one expand once allocated chunk of memory.

Answer (score 1):

> will the initial first 10 values still be there?

In C++, there will be *somewhere*, but you have lost your handle to them. They will be inaccessible. This constitures a memory leak.

```
int* array=new int[10]; // array points to dynamically allocated array
array=new int[15]; // array points to a completely different place now
```

In the example above, the `array` pointer is the only handle you have on the first dynamically allocated array. By making it point elsewhere, you leak the array.

Note also that in C++ the elements of the array are not zero initialized. In order to do that, you need to value initialize the array:

```
int* array=new int[10]();
//                    ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you cannot dynamically extend an array. There are different data structures for that like ArrayList.

In Java, in your example if no reference is left to the first array with size 10, it will be collected by GarbageCollector.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, if you can or not dynamically extend an array.

How does Vector internally work?

Comment: Use ArrayList instead of Vector unless you need it to be thread safe. It has an array inside it. When you fill all the space and need to add one mroe it copies everything to a larger array and releases references to previous array (so that it is garbage collected)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ new always returns a pointer.
The name of arrays is a pointer to the first element in the array so here is what would happen.

```
 int *array;           //get a point of type int
 array=new int[10];    //allocate 10 ints, and set the array ponter to the first one

 array = new int[15]   //allocate 15 ints, and set the array pointer to the first one
```

the problem is now we have no way of knowing where in memory the first 10 ints are. The operating systems "thinks" we are using it b/c we asked for it. but we cann't use it b/c we don't know where it is.

---

now for something helpful. Use vectors, vectors are objects in c++ that have dynamic memory allocation built into them, so you don't have to manually do it your self.

If you really want to see how it is done, you can make object that handle memory allocation your self.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I dynamically expand an array (without using Vector class, and without copying the array each time in another array with double capacity) in Java?

In `java.util.Arrays`, there are a lot of method to use. In your situation you need `copyOf`

[Api Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

```
array = Arrays.copyOf(array, 15);
```

Comment: _without copying the array each time_ ...

Comment: @jlordo I think OP means without *manually* copying the array each time ...

Comment: This is wrong. The array won't get expanded, you will simply get a newly allocated array. Any references to the old array would still point to the old array with the old size.

Comment: @BrunoReis Good argument... I didn't thought of the case that the array is shared...

Comment: So if the original array has size 10 and I do
array=Arrays.copyOf(array, 20), will I get a new array with the first 10 fields similar to the original one?

Comment: @Radu Yes. As apidocs stated: `Returns a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with zeros to obtain the specified length`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an equivalent in C++, which is Standard C++.

```
std::vector<int> array(10);
```

And then

```
array.resize(15);
```

The `vector` manages its storage memory exactly the way you expect. The `vector` has been designed to replace C's reallocated array pointers. To replace on-stack arrays, you have `std::array` since C++11. To replace on-stack VLAs, you will have `std::dynarray` in C++14 or C++17.

And don't get lured, `realloc` occasionally copies its data. (When it does not find enough space in-place to get your reallocated buffer)

About the equivalent of `realloc` for C++, no, there is no `renew` corresponding to `new` the way there is a `realloc` corresponding to `malloc`. And it is not something missing in the language. It has been addressed with the `std::vector` class. It manages its memory itself, it is efficient, and no, it is not unpure style to use it. It is the standard way in C++ to have an array that can resize.

Answer (score 0):

The best option in C++ is stl and `std::vector<int>` I have no idea why you can't use it but lets say, that you can't. Probably the best way:

```
const int c_startSize = 10;
const int c_increasing = 13;   //1.3

int * array;
int arraySize = c_startSize;
array = new int[arraySize];
//some code
//now we need to increase size of array.
int * tmp;
tmp = new int[arraySize * c_increasing / 10];
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    tmp[i] = array[i];
arraySize = arraySize * c_increasing / 10;
delete [] array;
array = tmp;
//some code
```

It is probably the only way. Of course you can use `realloc` or `memcpy` to copy values, but it is based on void pointers and for beginners usually it is more tricky. Hopefully this helped, don't forget to make a class or a struct for this thing, otherwise, it will be to much of mess.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, my answer includes C++ only, no JAVA.

Comment: Mostly off-topic.
Firstly, it's not STL it's Standard Library, despite the fact the most people make a confusion between them, they are different.
Secondly, I have asked for something completely different. 
Do you know what "without using vector, and without copying the array" means?
Thirdly, where did you get the idea that I am a beginner?
Fourthly, no it didn't help at all. It annoys me a great deal when people answer questions that were not asked.

Comment: Idea about your being beginner is because you want to make something yourself instead of using some trusted source like vector.